Mobile inference in a React Native App: use tensorflow in a native module or use directly Tensorflow.js in React Native?
I want to performance a face detection + face recognition in a React Native App offline, so I need to do my inference directly on mobile. I see that are many ways to do that, such as with Tensorflow.js. For better performance, it's preferable that: 1. Implement a Native Module with Tensorflow in Java (I could use an existing code that I have) or 2. Implement my code directly in React Native using Tensorflow.js? Is there any difference?
Any idea on what these different forms of implementation would result?

There are multiple things you have to do. I'm not sure but you can check this https://react-native-vision-camera.com/docs/guides/skia-frame-processors
and https://blog.swmansion.com/on-device-ai-ml-in-react-native-137918d0331b
It's not what you require but you might get idea how to archive that you want.
